# How do I fix the error E-1019 (DUPLICATE_FACTORS) when using categorical y-axis in Bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh, heatmap

I have a Pandas dataframe which has values for the y axis spread over 3 columns. Those I want to show in a [categorical y-axis](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html). Then I have a column for `x` and a column for the `color`. From those values I want to create a heatmap.

I created the following code, which returns the error `E-1019 (DUPLICATE_FACTORS): FactorRange must specify a unique list of categorical factors for an axis`

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, FactorRange, LinearColorMapper
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Greys256

mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette=Greys256, low=0, high=5, high_color = 'red')

df_in = pd.DataFrame([['cat1', 'ccat1', 'cccat1', 4, 20],['cat1', 'ccat1', 'cccat1', 5, 15],['cat1', 'ccat1', 'cccat1', 6, 10]], columns=['key1','key2', 'key3', 'x', 'color'])

factors = list(df_in[['key1', 'key2', 'key3']].astype(str).itertuples(index=False, name=None))

data = dict(
    y=factors,
    x=list(df_in['x'].astype(int)),
    color=list(df_in['color'].astype(int)),
)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=data)

p = figure(y_range=FactorRange(*factors))
p.rect(y='y', x='x', width=1, height=0.75, source = source, fill_color={'field': 'color', 'transform': mapper})

show(p)
```

When I construct the dictionary inside `data` manually by hardcoding it (including duplicated values in `key1-3`, I do not get this error.

Do I extract the dataframe wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out by myself:

The `FactorRange` needs to be unique while the factors in the y axis should keep having an entry for each value in the heatmap.

A list can be made unique with `list(set(factors)))`

```py
p = figure(y_range=FactorRange(*list(set(factors)))
```